# Como escolher qual foto aparecerá no Facebook ao compartilhar uma página?

Tags: html5

Acabei de fazer um site para um amigo que vai ser utilizado para um evento, a meio do site tem uma parte que apresenta os convidados especiais com descrição e tudo mais. Na hora de partilhar o link do site no Facebook, aparece a foto de um dos convidados e não a primeira foto presente no site, que é supostamente o cartaz.

Há algum tipo de comando para eu por a foto que quero como sendo a foto "principal" do site?

Answer (score 3):

Para a integração com Facebook, você precisa das tags `meta` do OpenGraph.

A da imagem especificamente é esta:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://dominio/imagem"/>
```

No caso, você pode inclusive selecionar uma imagem específica para o Facebook, com o recorte mais adequado para a exibição, e não necessariamente precisa ser alguma usada na página.

Se quiser adicionar várias imagens, basta colocar mais de uma vez a tag. Neste caso, o Facebook priorizará elas pela ordem que as tags `meta` foram colocadas no código, da primeira até a última, mas dependendo do contexto e do formato, pode usar outras. Veja mais detalhes e as dimensões ideais da imagem no link para a documentação oficial, ao final da resposta.

Obviamente que para uma melhor experiência de usuário, a imagem tem que fazer sentido no contexto, então é conveniente que seja algo que o usuário vá de fato encontrar ao clicar no link. Por exemplo, uma versão ou recorte de alguma parte relevante do cartaz, ou uma versão reformatada para exibição no Facebook.

Atente para todas as tags necessárias para especificar as definições do objeto, para que o Facebook reconheça os dados.

Mais detalhes na especificação:

> [Facebook Open Graph - Propriedades do objeto](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-properties)

Comment: Ja usei essa tag e nao funcionou e tambem ja apaguei as fotos dos convidados especiais e continua a aparecer na mesma mesmo com as tags

Comment: Como comentei, tem que fazer o opengraph com os ítens básicos corretamente, não apenas usar a tag solta. Além disso, no primeiro uso, se você não usar o Lint do facebook, pode demorar para o resultado aparecer. O caminho é basicamente este, mudar as imagens da página não vai resolver.

Comment: Se quiser testar a indexação do FB, o link é este: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/