# Problemas com exibição do meu site no facebook

Tags: facebook, html-meta-tag

Boa noite tenho as tags no meu site para compartilhamento no facebook

```
<meta name='og:title' content='Desapego Games - Troca, Compra e Venda de Games'/>
<meta name='og:url' content='http://desapegogames.com.br/' />
<meta name="description" content='A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!' />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://desapegogames.com.br/images/logoface.jpg" />      
<meta property='og:description' content='A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!' />
```

so que o facebook nbao inclui essa imagem da tag og:image
ele inclui qualquer outra imagem da pagina

no depurador do face mesmo atualizando o cache ele retorna que não tenho a tag na minha página.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém poderia me ajudar a consertar isso ? já tentei de tudo copiei o código de sites que funcionam e não resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa mensagem de erro provavelmente ocorre quando confunde o atributo `property` com `name`:

> The "og:****" property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Alguns você usou `name` outros usou `property`, o uso do opengraph é `property=""` para todos tags `og:`, conforme o http://ogp.me

Outro detalhe é que você usou assim:

```
<meta name='fb:app_id' content="324349677944444"/>
```

Mas o correto é:

```
<meta property='fb:app_id' content="324349677944444"/>
```

Conforme: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects

**Deve ficar assim:**

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="324349677944444" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Desapego Games - Troca, Compra e Venda de Games"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://desapegogames.com.br/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://desapegogames.com.br/images/logoface.jpg" />
<meta property="description" content="A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!" />
```

Um detalhe adicional, que **não influencia** em nada, apenas para ressaltar, se for HTML5 o `/>` é opcional e também se possivel não misturar as tag og com as normais, você pode pensar em mudar para apenas:

```
<!-- og -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="324349677944444">
<meta property="og:title" content="Desapego Games - Troca, Compra e Venda de Games"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://desapegogames.com.br/">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://desapegogames.com.br/images/logoface.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!">

<!-- meta -->
<meta name="description" content="A sua comunidade focada em compra,venda e troca de games e artigos Geek. E o melhor de tudo é grátis!">
```

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162276/3635